# Regex that restrict special characters, numbers and alphabets except UPPERCASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2008

I want to use regex to restrict users to enter special characters, numbers  and alphabets except UPPERCASE by adding a constraint while creating a table.  User is allowed to enter only UPPERCASE alphabets. I have tried the following.

```
CONSTRAINT chk_spl_chars_model CHECK (Model LIKE '%[A-Z]+%')
```

This didnt work. It is not allowing to enter any value. Any Help is appreciated.

Following is the query u yse to create table

```
CREATE TABLE Cars(
        Model VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
        ,CONSTRAINT chk_spl_chars_model CHECK (Model LIKE '%^[A-Z]+$%')

);
```

This is accepting any value to be inserted even lowercase and special characters

Comment: try `^[A-Z]+$` also?

Comment: Have you set your collation to be case sensitive? If not then A would match both "A" and "a" if it is case-insensitive.

Comment: Its not case sensitive

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen, to overcome case sensitivity, convert the string to **UPPER CASE** before inserting after making the necessary checking or restricted characters

Answer (score 1):

You must using collation in your constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT chk_spl_chars_model CHECK (not (Model COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AI LIKE '%[a-z]%'))
```

You can using following format too (change collation of model column):

```
CREATE TABLE Cars(
        Model VARCHAR(10) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AI NOT NULL
        ,CONSTRAINT chk_spl_chars_model CHECK (NOT Model LIKE '%[a-z]%')

);
```

Comment: I think you need to drop `%` signs

Comment: `a-z` expands out to `aAbBcCdD...yYz`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a case sensitive collation, as [mehdi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25419146/15498) indicated, but you also need to change what you're looking for:

```
CREATE TABLE Cars(
    Model VARCHAR(10) collate Latin1_General_CS_AI NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT chk_spl_chars_model CHECK (
          Model
            NOT LIKE '%[^ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%')
);
```

You want:

- a `NOT LIKE` because we want to search for characters that we *don't* want to appear
- `%` matches "any character" so we want to match any number of characters
- then `^` *within* a `[]` block indicates to match any character *not* included in the set
- `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` because even in most case sensitive collations, lower case letters appear between upper case letters if you use a range expression like `A-Z`.

So the complete pattern says "match any number of characters, then one character that isn't an upper case character, then any number of characters" - and so, in other words, it matches any string that contains at least one non-upper case character - and if we match that, then we reject that value (because of the `NOT LIKE`).

`^` (outside of `[]`), `$` and `+` have no special meaning for [`LIKE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms179859.aspx) patterns.

Comment: You could also do `CHECK (Model COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z]%')`. I wonder if setting the column collation is necessary. It would certainly cause conditions like `Model = 'abc'` and `Model = 'ABC'` to produce different results, although it is not clear if that is necessary in this situation. Either way, it would also make you always specify a collation when matching against another table's column if that other column happened to use the default collation and the default was different from `Latin1_General_CS_AI`.